# Session is getting destroyed randomly

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a CakePHP 3.6 application hosted on Apache2 in local and Nginx in production.
I recently found a problem when visiting the website, the session got destroyed randomly when browsing normally. It happen really often (clicking 3/4 links).
I never had this problem before and didn't change anything specific before having this.
Sometimes I got this error:

`Warning (2): session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed.`

but most of the time it happens without any error in logs.

Could you help me find where this come from?

Comment: Hi, Not without seeing the code

Comment: _Small Note_ I think it would make more sense to have a development server that matches your LIVE environment, then maybe you would have some way to test this odd situation

Comment: Do you have APC turned on? Kill it with fire, for some reason Nginx and apc don't play well together. Also, try restarting fpm.

Comment: Agree with @RiggsFolly. even if you can't make dev match prod because reasons, at least use the same stack :-)

Comment: Which part if the code would you like tout see? Aldo APC is off and the problem is here with apache and nginx so it doesn't seem specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `$this->Auth->setUser()` in the AppController.php (beforeFilter to be exact). I didn't think it was coming from CakePHP sorry :/

So the solution is to not use Auth related function or at least setUser in the AppController's beforeFilter().

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are "not" switching between HTTP and HTTPS modes between pages.

Comment: I checked and I'm not :/

Comment: You should also check to see where the production server is storing session data, and that you are not running out of space on that partition. This is a very common cause of losing sessions.

Comment: It's using /tmp/ but the problem is here even when storing sessions in Redis